# Safecracker Image field returns image source as http not https

Tags: safecracker, safecracker-file

I've got a template view served via https with a Safecracker form that contains a Safecracker File field ({field:saef_image}) where the image source is returned as http:// instead of https://. The Safecracker delete image (write_mode_close.png) is also served unsecure. Since the assets aren't being served secure I'm getting the warning via the SSL status, which I want to fix. I'm using secure_action="yes" and secure_return="yes". Any ideas on what's going on here or if there is a modification of the core that anyone knows of?

Thanks for any help in advance!

EE v2.6.1, Safecracker v2.1

Comment: In your file upload preferences what have you got in the "URL of Upload Directory" field, http or https?

Comment: It's currently http because it serves images to a non https template as well. Also, the admin is not under https.

Comment: Making the upload directory https worked for the Safecracker field - the path is being returned relative in the template and the admin is fine to return https:// while not under https. The Safecracker image write_mode_close.png is still http, however.